# Does Android's coreLibraryDesugaring provide any Java features not already available on API level 26?

Tags: android, java-8, java-11, jdk-desugaring

Desugaring makes many java 8 and [java 11](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java11-default-support-table) features available for apps with lower `minSdkVersion`s.
With a `minSdkVersion` of 26 or higher, is there any benefit to continued use of the desugaring library?

I tried increasing `minSdkVersion` to 26, and removing `coreLibraryDesugaring`, and did not encounter any errors. But are there any Java APIs which I have lost access to?